# Android studio navigation drawer icon color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

All my fragments use red action bar, so white navigation drawer icon looks good. But for one fragment I need white action bar and drawer icon not visible. So I have to change drawer icon to red. But I can't find how to do this.

How to change icon to red color?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create style like this for your required activity `styles.xml`

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

And then add it to you Activity theme like this:

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

Comment: This is works but I have one activity and many fragments. Some fragments with red action bar and one with white. If I add this to activity theme drawer icon will be red everywhere not only in fragment with white action bar

Comment: You can use this code if you just want to change color with default icon       `toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);` and add this where you adding fragment with desire color in your activity

Comment: `toolbar.getNavigati‌​onIcon()` return null. It return drawble only when I set it manually with `setNavigationIcon` method. But I don't know the name of default menu icon to set it manually.

Comment: I have not set any navigation icon.But its working fine in my device

Comment: Put that code after `DrawerLayout` is initialized and created. i.e after navigation listener is set

Comment: It works! When I use this code after `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` it works! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Been trying to do this myself and through trial and error came up with the following

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

int color = getResources().getColor(getResources().getIdentifier("red", "color", getPackageName()));
toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(color);
```

I prefer this method personally as you can replace "red" with a variable which suited my needs perfectly